# How to run a macro that is stored in a module in a workbook after the Workbook.Close method?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data connection from my Excel file to an Access file. The issue is that, you cannot establish a data connection to an Access file if it's being used. So the workaround is to actually copy the Access file that is being used and store it in a different location, then the Excel file will connect to that copy.

However, the duplicated Access file will need to be updated eventually, but it cannot be updated when the Excel file that is connecting to it is open. So the only way to actually update the duplicated Access file is to close the Excel file then overwrite it. I plan to achieve this by using 2 steps:

1.) Close the Excel file

```
Workbooks("Excel-file.xlsm").Close
```

2.) Run a batch file that will update the Access file:

```
Sub TryShell()

  Dim PathCrnt As String

  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  Call Shell(PathCrnt & "\TryShell.bat " & PathCrnt)

End Sub
```

The issue is that the lines after closing the excel file won't run anymore (for example):

```
Workbooks("Excel-file.xlsm").Close
MsgBox "Hello"
```

Hello will not display anymore.

For those interested in seeing my connection string to MS Access:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
User ID=Admin;
Data Source=C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Test.MDB;
Mode=Share Deny Write;
Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0; (changing to a value of 1 still results to an error to connect)
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False
```

Comment: How do you update your Access file? Is there a macro inside the Access file that you need to run for the updates to be done?

Comment: I would rather try to modify my connections to Access. I am quite sure you CAN read from Access even if db is open (as long it's not opened in exclusive mode)

Comment: @Teasel The main Access file is updated by other users. However it is very inconvenient for them to always close the main file so I need to make duplicates based on the main Access file that will keep updating periodically.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I am actually searching for a way to do so. I have actually asked 2 related questions in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1355046/how-can-a-read-only-purpose-data-connection-to-ms-excel-access-from-ms-excel-pre/1355100?noredirect=1#comment2034060_1355100 and https://superuser.com/questions/1355402/how-to-make-a-read-only-data-connection-to-a-read-write-locked-ms-access-using-m but there might be no option. I tried disabling the `record-locking-level` but it didn't work

Comment: @Pherdindy first step is to make sure the db is not open in exclusive mode. You can easily test it by opening 2 instances of Access on the same pc. 2d point is HOW do you read that data ? You should perhaps provide details on your data connection properties?

Comment: btw I can't see your images from my workplace (firewalled)

Comment: How are you connecting to your DB from Excel?  I've just checked, and an old Workbook using an ADODB connection to an Access DB seems to work fine when someone has the DB open - even when the specific *Table* is open in Access.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I'll check whether it's in exclusive mode tomorrow at work. Although I saw in the settings something like `Default open mode = Shared`--which is the default, the other option is `Exclusive` which isn't selected.

Comment: I connect by going to the `Data` tab -> `From Database` -> `From Microsoft Access Database` in MS Excel then I just refresh the data through the connection

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I am able to open 2 instances of Access in my computer. However, when I try to open the file that I want to connect to, I can only open one instance. When I try to open it again on the same PC, it will only go to the window of the first instance, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need data from `Excel-file.xlsm` anymore, you can put the macro in your Personal Macro Workbook.

Comment: Right. I didn't consider that but I might be able to work with that although the issue is what if there are many different users on different computers? I believe the personal macro workbook won't carry over. All files is shared over a network/cloud and has to be robust when anyone uses it

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, @Patrick Honorez makes the most sense. It does not make sense to design concurrency support like this..

Comment: Yeah that was the solution I thought about at first, but I cannot seem to find a way to do it. My access options is defaulted to be shared to begin with: under `Client Settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Default open mode = Shared` and `Default record locking = No locks` but still cannot establish a connection when in use by another user.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your situation, and indeed, I couldn't refresh the table once the db was open.  So I went to the Connection Properties, Definition tab, Connection String, and I changed:

```
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0
```

to

```
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1
```

Now I can refresh the table in Excel even if it is open in Access.

Comment: I tried on both of the computers at office one with Excel 2007 and Excel 2016 changing the connection string value of `JET OLEDB:Database Locking Mode` to 1 still makes me unable to make a data connection with an open Access file. A person was able to offer a code to actually extract data from an Access file as seen in this superuser post: https://superuser.com/questions/1355402/how-to-make-a-read-only-data-connection-to-a-read-write-locked-ms-access-using-m/1355468#1355468 but I am still interested in making a more conventional data connection first before using VBA.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with my Access being exclusive or not, I added the connection string on the main post--as well as a comment regarding my Access being exclusive or not.